# UISearchBar Staying at top when seguing from tableview results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I created a search with 2 `UINavigationcontrollers` and with 2 `UITableViewControllers`. One for displaying the initial results, and then another `TableViewController` for when displaying searched results.

This is where i think the issue occurs. I use this method to show the resultsTableViewController where i make it the top view controller.

Now when i segue from the results view controller, the `UISearchBar` stays on top. When i code `[vc.tableView setDelegate: self];`.

it removes the issue of the search bar staying but then screws up the `didselectrowatindex` path which i need to identify because the results aren't the same from the original and the results `Tableviewcontroller`.

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{

    // Set searchString equal to what's typed into the searchbar
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;


    [self updateFilteredContentForAirlineName:searchString];

    // If searchResultsController
    if (self.searchController.searchResultsController) {

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;

        // Present SearchResultsTableViewController as the topViewController
        SearchResultsTableViewController *vc = (SearchResultsTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;

        // Update searchResults
        vc.searchResults = self.searchResults;

        // And reload the tableView with the new data
        [vc.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Here's a project i mocked up that has the issue included.

http://expirebox.com/download/10533c5d386618b95bb39bd1dc886ace.html

Comment: you want to remove search bar when you going to next screen

Comment: Dont do segue use push controller so you can remove your search bar in next screen

Comment: ok wait in will send code

Answer (score 0):

try to extend your next viewcontroller to class.so i will create new data class and extend to viewcontroller than paste this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    data *next=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"datascreen"];
    [self presentViewController:next animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ok bro try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        data *next=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"datascreen"];
[self.navigationController next animated:YES];
}
```

both class use this code.try this if any problem than tell me

Comment: with this method, the view controller i want to present, i need to have it pushed. so that theres a navigation controller, your way doesn't provide that.